# Proof of quotient rule using Caratheodory derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I can prove sum and product rule for differentiation using Caratheodory derivative (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CaratheodoryDerivative.html).  However I'm not sure how to do quotient rule (or its special case $1/g$).  Can anyone give a hint or the main step to put $1/g$ in the form we need?

Comment: I think you meant how to use Caratheorody's Theorem to prove the quotient rule...?

Comment: @DonAntonio Can you link the theorem?  When I google it other unrelated stuff comes up...

Comment: http://blog.nus.edu.sg/ma3110/2016/01/18/6-1-the-derivative/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $g(x) -g(a) =\phi(x) (x-a) $. In particular, $g$ is continuous at $x=a$.  Then 
$$\frac1{g(x)} -\frac1{g(a)} \ =\ \frac{g(a) -g(x)} {g(x) g(a)} \ =\ - \frac{\phi(x) (x-a)} {g(x) g(a)}  \ =\\
=\ -\frac{\phi(x)} {g(x) g(a)} (x-a) $$
where the last fraction is continuous at $a$, provided $g(a) \ne0$.

Answer (score 0):

Put $\;h(x):=\cfrac1{g(x)}\;$ , then at $\;x=a\;$ , where $\;g(a)\neq0\;$ , we get

$$\frac{h(x)-h(a)}{x-a}=\frac{\frac1{g(x)}-\frac1{g(a)}}{x-a}=\frac{g(a)-g(x)}{g(x)g(a)(x-a)}=$$

$$=-\frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}\cdot\frac1{g(x)g(a)}\xrightarrow[x\to a]{}\phi(a)-\cdot\frac1{g(a)^2}=-\frac{g'(a)}{g(a)^2}$$

using the fact that $\;\phi(x)\xrightarrow[x\to a]{}g'(a)\;$ in Caratheorody's Theorem and that we assume, of course, that $\;g'(a)\;$ exists.